# git-crypt git pull does not work

Tags: git, encryption, github, repository

I'm trying to work with git and attempting to pull but I keep getting a message saying "Already up to date". Here is what I attempted
(Assuming that remote has already been set up as per the instructions [here](https://github.com/bluss/git-remote-gcrypt))

`git add .`
`git commit -m "hello"`
`git push origin master`

At this point everything is commited successfully. However, if I try doing `git pull origin master` after removing the file from my working directory. I get this message:

[image]

It claims that everything is up to date when I have just pushed a file earlier.

UPDATE: I've discovered that the encryption [method](https://github.com/bluss/git-remote-gcrypt) doesnt handle merging

Answer (score 0):

> `git pull origin master` after removing the file from my working directory

That wouldn't do anything, considering there is nothing to fetch (your local repo already has what has been pushed, there is nothing to fetch)

In order to get back your files, you can do a:

```
git checkout HEAD -- .
```

Comment: I've tried `rm hello.txt`<br> `git checkout Head --`<br> and this retrieves my files but doesnt handle merging. Is there an alternative to `git merge`?

Comment: @ShreyKumar it doesn't handle merging, because there is nothing to merge. There is nothing to merge, because there is nothing to fetch (pull is fetch + merge). There is nothing to fetch because you just pushed it.

Comment: But that isn't true since I just removed the file "hello.txt" locally. Its meant to pull it back from the repo?

Comment: @ShreyKumar the `git checkout HEAD -- .` should have restored the `hello.txt` (without merging anything, since there is nothing to merge)